# Android library project - how to get context?

Tags: android

I have been happily refactoring code from different versions of the same app (paid/free) into Android library projects so that the actual apps can simply customize the library and reduce code duplication.

One thing I'm started to wonder is what `getApplicationContext()` inside the library code means? Is is the same `ApplicationContext` as one would get from the child apps? What happens when I access `SharedPreferences` from a library project's `getApplicationContext()` instead of the original app's `getApplicationContext()`? Will the `SharedPreferences` file be same or different?

What if I had used the activity to access `SharedPreferences`? Does it matter that the activity is now a library activity and not the original app? Is the `SharedPreferences` the same?

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the APK is packaged up then all classes will be belong to the main application.

call getApplicationContext().getPackageName() and it will return the app's package name, and not the library's package.

I have the same setup for a free/paid application and no issues when I moved my classes into a library project.

However you have to check your xml files (manifest, widgets, etc.) to use the full package name of your library project.

Comment: I did some testing and saw that SharedPreferences is not affected. And I also see that getPackageName() returns the child app's package. Google has provided limited documentation for libraries.. thanks for confirming.

Comment: In my case SharedPreferences were affected and `getPackageName()` returned in each case the same results. But there was a difference in `context.toString() `

Answer (score 1):

A library project is almost like having all the code in one project. There are a couple of things to watch out for related to namespaces but generally it works very well.

e.g. Your library has its own namespace

Library package name = uk.co.lib
Main App package name = uk.co.app

Activities in the library that you want tro access from the main app have to be added to the app manifest. Activity named A in library project would be added to manifest in main app like this:

```
<activity android:name="uk.co.lib.A">
```

Accessing shared preferences etc would give the same result from either namespace and would return the preferences for the app.

There is only one application so there is only one ApplicationContext